# If dentro de if dentro while dentro de while (lento)

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um dúvida acerca de loop while:

tenho a seguinte `query`:

```
 $sql = "SELECT id,cod,nome,cnpj,insc_estadual,tributacao FROM empresas_base WHERE tributacao = '$filtro_regime_nome' AND responsavel = '$user' GROUP BY id ORDER BY id";
```

Essa `query` inicia um loop `while`, e dentro desse loop realizo outra consulta com base no 'cod' da empresa.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM controle_fiscal WHERE empresa = '$empresaCod' AND mes_correspondente = '$m' AND ano_correspondente = '$a' GROUP BY id ORDER BY id ";
```

E com essa segunda `query` eu efetuo mais um loop `while` dentro do loop anterior para pegar os valores que eu preciso, e ainda por cima, dentro desse segundo loop, existem varios `ifs` dentro de `ifs`, o que faz com que a consulta acabe ficando mais lenta do que o esperado.

**OBS:** Os loops e `ifs` são tratados por funções da `classe model`, não estão dispostos de forma linear, mas mesmo assim não deixam de ser `ifs`

Dúvida:

> 1 - É correto fazer isso ?
>
> 2 - Existe outra maneira de efetuar isso com apenas uma query ?

Comment: Correto é relativo, no geral dá para otimizar a maneira de fazer, se postar como fez até o momento talvez seja possivel fornecer uma sugestão melhor.

Comment: Tudo que funciona e traz um resultado satisfatório é correto. Claro, que há casos em que podemos otimizar para ganharmos alguns nanosegundos ou, não sobrecarregar o servidor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maneira de fazer isso só com uma query é utilizando o `JOIN`:

> OBS: Fiz um exemplo de como ficaria, mas como não conheço seu banco de dados, pode ser que precise de alguns ajustes, te aconselho a dar uma estudada no JOIN e ver como ficaria melhor no seu caso.

```
SELECT e.id,e.cod,e.nome,e.cnpj,e.insc_estadual,e.tributacao, cf.*
FROM controle_fiscal cf
INNER JOIN empresas_base e ON cf.empresa = e.cod
WHERE e.tributacao = '$filtro_regime_nome' AND e.responsavel = '$user' AND cf.mes_correspondente = '$m' AND cf.ano_correspondente = '$a'
GROUP BY e.id 
ORDER BY e.id
```

Alguns pontos merecem atenção,como:

- campos com mesmo nome;
- em qual tabela fazer o join;
- a forma que vc quer os registros retornados;

Entre outros;

Aqui tem um link para vc dar uma olhada: http://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-join-entenda-como-funciona-o-retorno-dos-dados/31006